# Chapter and section name in footer beneath page number

Tags: header-footer, chapters

I would like to generate something like the pictures below. 
I already got the blue line and the numbering. Now i would like to also show the chapter name on the left pages, and the section name of the latest section on the right page.

I already tried to use \leftmark in the page numbering. But then it will be on the wrong side of the line.

How can i do this? Any hints are welcome :)

Thanks to all who will contribute :)

[image]
[image]

--- Edit

Here is the minimal code which shows, how i made the actual design:

```
\documentclass[twoside=true,a4paper,1.5pt,titlepage=on,]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{chaptercolor}{rgb}{0.36,0.73,0.82}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyfootoffset[OR]{1.85cm}
    \fancyfoot[OR]{%
        {\ }%\tgherosfont%
        {\color{chaptercolor}\rule[-90pt]{0.8mm}{100pt}}%
        \hspace*{10pt}\begin{minipage}[b]{1.5cm}%
            \color{chaptercolor}\normalsize\textbf{\thepage}%
        \end{minipage}%
    }
    \fancyfootoffset[EL]{1.85cm}
    \fancyfoot[EL]{%
        %\tgherosfont%
        \begin{minipage}[b]{1.5cm}%
            \raggedleft\color{chaptercolor}\normalsize\textbf{\thepage \leftmark}%
        \end{minipage}%
        \hspace*{10pt}{\color{chaptercolor}\rule[-90pt]{0.8mm}{100pt}}%
    }
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
}

\fancypagestyle{maincontentstyle}{%
    \pagestyle{plain}
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyfootoffset[OR]{1.85cm}
    \fancyfoot[OR]{%
        {\ }\tgherosfont\footnotesize%
        \rightmark%
        \hspace*{0.75cm}{\color{ctcolorfooterline}\rule[-90pt]{1.25pt}{100pt}}%
        \hspace*{10pt}\begin{minipage}[b]{1.5cm}%
            \color{chaptercolor}\normalsize\textbf{\thepage  }%
        \end{minipage}%
    }
    \fancyfootoffset[EL]{1.85cm}
    \fancyfoot[EL]{%
        \tgherosfont\footnotesize%
        \begin{minipage}[b]{1.5cm}%
            \raggedleft\color{chaptercolor}\normalsize\textbf{\thepage }%
        \end{minipage}%
        \footnotesize%
        \hspace*{10pt}{\color{chaptercolor}\rule[-90pt]{1.25pt}{100pt}}%
        \hspace*{0.75cm}\leftmark%
    }
}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfootoffset[OR]{1.85cm}
\fancyfoot[OR]{%
    {\ }%\tgherosfont%
    {\color{chaptercolor}\rule[-90pt]{0.8mm}{100pt}}%
    \hspace*{10pt}\begin{minipage}[b]{1.5cm}%
        \color{chaptercolor}\normalsize\textbf{\thepage}%
    \end{minipage}%
}
\fancyfootoffset[EL]{1.85cm}
\fancyfoot[EL]{%
    %\tgherosfont%
    \begin{minipage}[b]{1.5cm}%
        \raggedleft\color{chaptercolor}\normalsize\textbf{\thepage}%
    \end{minipage}%
    \hspace*{10pt}{\color{chaptercolor}\rule[-90pt]{0.8mm}{100pt}}%
}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}


\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

    \tableofcontents

    \Blinddocument


\end{document}
```

Comment: Please add a MWE showing how you get the blue line and the page number. A possible answer depends on the package used for header and footer (`fancyhdr`, `titleps`, `scrlayer-scrpage`, ...) and maybe it depends on the document class too.

Comment: @esdd im Sorry, you are right. I have added the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that it is not recommended to use `fancyhdr` together with a KOMA-Script class. So here is a suggestion using `scrlayer-scrpage` (part of the KOMA-Script bundle):

```
\documentclass[
  twoside=true,
  %a4paper,% default
  %%1.5pt,% unknown option!
  titlepage=on
]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text

\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{chaptercolor}{rgb}{0.36,0.73,0.82}

\colorlet{ctcolorchapterline}{chaptercolor}
\colorlet{ctcolorchapternum}{chaptercolor}
\colorlet{ctcolorfooterline}{chaptercolor}
\colorlet{ctsectiontitles}{chaptercolor}
\colorlet{ctcolorfootertitle}{chaptercolor}
\colorlet{ctcolorfootermark}{black}


\usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}% sets pagestyle scrheadings automatically
\clearpairofpagestyles
\lefoot*{\hspace{10pt}\leftmark}
\rofoot*{\rightbotmark\hspace{10pt}}
%\rofoot*{\ifstr{\rightmark}{}{\rightbotmark}{\rightmark}\hspace{10pt}}% alternative

\addtokomafont{pagefoot}{\normalfont\usekomafont{disposition}\color{ctcolorfootertitle}}
\renewcommand\chaptermarkformat{\textcolor{ctcolorfootermark}{\chapapp~\thechapter\autodot\enskip}}
\renewcommand\sectionmarkformat{\textcolor{ctcolorfootermark}{\thesection\autodot\enskip}}

\AddLayersToPageStyle{scrheadings}{pagenumber.odd,pagenumber.even}
\AddLayersToPageStyle{plain.scrheadings}{pagenumber.odd,pagenumber.even}
\DeclareNewLayer[
  foreground,
  oddpage,
  foot,
  contents={%
    \hfill
    \makebox[0pt][l]{%
      \pagenumberrule
      \hspace*{10pt}%
      \pagemark
    }%
  }
]{pagenumber.odd}
\DeclareNewLayer[
  clone=pagenumber.odd,
  evenpage,
  contents={%
    \makebox[0pt][r]{%
      \pagemark
      \hspace*{10pt}%
      \pagenumberrule
    }%
  }
]{pagenumber.even}
\newcommand*\pagenumberrule{%
  {\color{ctcolorfooterline}\rule[\dimexpr-10cm+\ht\strutbox\relax]{1.25pt}{10cm}}%
}
\addtokomafont{pagenumber}{\usekomafont{disposition}}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Woow!!! You are so awsome :) Thanks so much!!! It works. But i got an error: Package scrlayer Error: cannot define `\newpagestyle'. } But the pdf still renders... strange

Comment: Do you load package `titleps` too? Note that you can use only one of the packages `scrlayer-scrpage`, `fancyhdr`, `titleps`, `scrpage2`.

Comment: No, i only load: mdframed, listings, calc, csquotes, inputenc, prahicx, geometry, caption, etoolbox, titlesec, hyperref, fontspec, scrlayer-scrpage. By the way, it does not work for page 1 and 2. Only from page 3... on

Comment: Do not use package `titlesec` together with a KOMA-Script class ... Use the KOMA-Script features to adjust the layout of the sectioning commands.

Comment: Ok, i would like to switch titlesec to an alternative. the problem is, that im quite new to latex and i dont know how i could switch my code to something other

Comment: Ok you were right. After removing titlesec it is working without errors. But still only from page 3 on... page 1 and two does not include the chapter informations nor the section info

Comment: Chapter pages uses pagestyle `plain` by default. I have changed my answer to add the footer entries for `plain` pages too.

Comment: so nice, thank you very much! Now i just have to migrate `\titleformat{\chapter}[display]%` to KOMA Script. But for that i opened a new question. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/491349/convert-titlesec-titleformat-to-koma-script - Again thank you very much!